# I have a big problem with the repositories

Tags: command-line, apt, ppa, repository

I have installed Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo a week ago in my computer. When I try to add a new repository with this command (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa` this is only an example) the terminal shows this text when I do a update with sudo apt-get update.

```
E: El repositorio «ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu disco Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

[image]

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you copy the text from the image linked into your question so it appears as text. Highlight the text and mark it up as code so it is formatted properly.

Comment: You added a PPA that does not provide 19.04 packages. Remove the PPA - the packages it provides are *incompatible* with your release of Ubuntu.

Comment: PPA's are 3rd party repositories, so security is up to you.  ie. you need to check support your release?, are well maintained?, you trust the person/group who created/maintain them? etc.   We can't copy/paste from the picture; but if you do you'll discover there is no 'disco' (19.04) support as @user535733 already stated.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Comment: E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu disco Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
This is the text from the terminal...